# Keeping active menu option's background the same colour

Tags: css, superfish

I have a Superfish menu that, when I hover over it and the sub-menu comes into view, I wish to keep a certain `background-color` for the selected option.

I have written this, however, it doesn't seem to apply:

```
.sf-menu ul li:hover > a {background-color: #da2026;}
```

Would it work if I targeted the element itself and used a `<` arrow to work backwards?

Comment: try `.sf-menu ul li:hover` maybe post a jsfiddle as well?

Comment: Hi Horen, Will try get a fiddle for you shortly :)

Comment: hi Vector, no it didnt

Answer (score 0):

This could be a good place to start

```
.sf-menu li li a:hover, .sf-menu li.sfHover li a:hover {
    background-color: #da2026;
}
```

or maybe just

```
.sf-menu li li.sfHover a{
    background-color: #da2026;
}
```

Comment: i will try this vector, its the styling of the parent so to speak of the children